# Code for looping through a list without exceeding range

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, range

I am trying to solve the following problem in Python 3.

*Loop through each element in word_list, printing the current element and the next element, separated by a space, in each loop*

The problem is that I exceed the range when I get to the last index, but am not sure how to modify the range object to fix this problem. Any ideas on how to modify this?

Code:

```
word_list=["Willie", "likes", "sleeping", "and", "eating"]
phrase_str=""
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    phrase_str= word_list[i] + " " + word_list[i+1]
    print(phrase_str)
```

Output

```
Willie likes 
likes sleeping 
sleeping and 
and eating
```

Error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-aba2a7894c1a> in <module>
      2 phrase_str=""
      3 for i in range(len(word_list)):
----> 4     phrase_str= word_list[i] + " " + word_list[i+1]
      5     print(phrase_str)
      6 

IndexError: list index out of range
​
```

Comment: Stop earlier: `for i in range(len(word_list) - 1):`.

Comment: I should note this isn't the most Pythonic way to loop over a list. `for word in word_list:...` would be better. If you really need the indices, use `enumerate`: `for i, word in enumerate(word_list): ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is an arbitary error!

[image: this is the length of the lsit]

The length of the list is 5, however indexing starts at 0, so the first element corresponds with index 0. hence the list range is out of bounds, juat use [len(word_list) - 1] and lop through! Hope this helps!

Comment: don't include images instead it's recommended to add code snippets.

Comment: hey, I am new to stack overflow, could you tell me how to do that? thanks

Comment: Even though it's recommended to add code snippets, I'm choosing this as the answer because it explains in layman's terms, the issue that I'm having.

Comment: @sarthak_thepythonguy triple backticks for code blocks. Single backticks for lines of code. For more details, see here. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

If you are coding in python always use "Pythonic" approach:

```py
word_list=["Willie", "likes", "sleeping", "and", "eating"]
for w1, w2 in zip(word_list, word_list[1:]):
    print(w1, w2)
```

Output:

```
Willie likes
likes sleeping
sleeping and
and eating
```

Answer (score 1):

if you make `len(word_list) - 1` it won't come to the end of list

```
word_list=["Willie", "likes", "sleeping", "and", "eating"]
phrase_str=""
for i in range(len(word_list) - 1):
    phrase_str= word_list[i] + " " + word_list[i+1]
    print(phrase_str)
```